# How to pass a group of numbers into PayPal checkout button?

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, paypal

I am building a lottery web application where customers can select their own numbers or get 4 random numbers. How can I carry these numbers that the customer inputs/randomly generates into my shopping cart / paypal button?
Thanks for any help.
This is my code so far for the generation of random lottery numbers on JSP page.

```
<div id="num1" class="ball col-md-2"><span id="one"></span></div>
<div id="num2" class="ball col-md-2"><span id="two"></span></div>
<div id="num3" class="ball col-md-2"><span id="three"></span></div>
<div id="num4" class="ball col-md-2"><span id="four"></span></div>
                               
                           
 <%-- onclick to execute JavaScript function--%>      
 <button onclick="random()">QuickPick!</button>
</div>
```

This is the JS file to execute the random numbers to be generated.

```
function random(){
 //selects the 4 circles on the page
var one= document.getElementById('one');
var two= document.getElementById('two');
var three= document.getElementById('three');
var four= document.getElementById('four');


//create random number for each of the circles between 1-30
var a = Math.floor(Math.random()*30);
var b = Math.floor(Math.random()*30);
var c = Math.floor(Math.random()*30);
var d = Math.floor(Math.random()*30);


//put the random number into each of the 4 circles
one.textContent = a;
two.textContent = b;
three.textContent = c;
four.textContent = d;

}
```

I have set up a PayPal REST API integration by following instructions on the website, I also can use a buy now smart button from PayPal. My question is, how can I issue the customers a receipt of the numbers they have selected up successful purchase of the ticket? Is there a way to pass the values of the JS code into the PayPal checkout page, any help is greatly appreciated as I cannot find a way to do this, thanks.

Comment: [javascriptisnotjava.com](http://javascriptisnotjava.com)

Answer (score 1):

In the [Integrate Checkout guide](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/), under 'Add and modify the code', the sixth entry shows how to add item information.

Here is the example given there of an items array containing one item with quantity two in this case:

```
    createOrder: function(data, actions) {
      return actions.order.create({
         "purchase_units": [{
            "amount": {
              "currency_code": "USD",
              "value": "100",
              "breakdown": {
                "item_total": {  /* Required when including the `items` array */
                  "currency_code": "USD",
                  "value": "100"
                }
              }
            },
            "items": [
              {
                "name": "First Product Name", /* Shows within upper-right dropdown during payment approval */
                "description": "Optional descriptive text..", /* Item details will also be in the completed paypal.com transaction view */
                "unit_amount": {
                  "currency_code": "USD",
                  "value": "50"
                },
                "quantity": "2"
              },
            ]
          }]
      });
    },
```

To apply this from your own code, you will likely want to use a JavaScript function to construct an items array with your desired items names or description. Use that items array in your button's purchase_units.